# Entity Framework Error Code in SQL code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I have an ASPX page where I formally used EF to code it's back-end then I switched back to SQL when EF proved too hard to debug.

When I was using EF I got this error

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>   Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported.
>   Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().

Unfortunately, I am no logger using EF in fact there is no EF code in the said page just SQL. Is there any reason why I should be getting this error still. I am thinking caching but not sure.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Probably requires a rebuild. But really, too hard to debug? What do you mean?

Comment: What I mean by hard is that : What I wanted to achieve with EF was pretty trivial "just retrieve some records from a DB and bind to a GridView" then I started getting the above error and after spending time online, I couldn't get a suitable solution, So I switched back to SQL and yet I still get error relating to EF. Funny thing is that the solution works on my Local machine but the error shows up on the on-line server.Note: Am working with another developer who uses EF but I use SQL for all my project modules